# Is there a list of applications which are know to leak or not to leak information when using with Tor?

Tags: proxy-leaks, verification

Some applications can either leak sensitive information through the Tor channel or they can make communication outside of the Tor channel which could lead to identification of your computer in the Tor network.

- Is there a list of applications which are known for such leaks?
- Is there a list of applications where such leaks were not observed?
- Is there an initiative trying to create and maintain such lists?

Comment: Any such list would also need to explicitly list the version of the application tested, as application fix and introduce bugs and features over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some applications can either leak sensitive information through the Tor channel or they can make communication outside of the Tor channel which could lead to identification of your computer in the Tor network.

Correct.

> Is there a list of applications which are known for such leaks?

The most central place is the [TorifyHOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO) in The Tor Project's wiki.

> Is there a list of applications where such leaks were not observed?

Proving a negative is impossible. You can only scrutinize applications yourself or take your chances and use recommended applications. Probably the most popular, best supported and most used application is the [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) by The Tor Project. Still, proxy-bypass bugs occasionally [get caught](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/firefox-security-bug-proxy-bypass-current-tbbs).

> Is there an initiative trying to create and maintain such lists?

Not really. There is only the [TorifyHOWTO](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO), but there is little activity. From my personal experience, due to low activity, non-existant moderation activity and edit wars, editors aren't motivated.